# How to reset Xcode 4 shortcut keys

Tags: xcode4

How do I reset Xcode 4 shortcuts keys as default?

Xcode -> Performance -> Key binding

I found I set something wrong, but cannot find a way to reset as original. 
How do I do? Reinstall Xcode 4?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Just click "+" to add a new Command Set and select `Default` (not `Duplicate Default`), then delete your old set.