# How to get a list of global shortcut on the mac?

Tags: macos, shortcut

Xcode default shortcut for `Comment Selection` is `cmd + /` but it not working on my mac

first I try to set it from `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcut > app shortcuts` but it still not work.

then I try to Create other User to test it, when I use Other account to open Xcode and try that shortcut, it work!!

so I guest maybe the shortcut `cmd + /` is using by some app for global shortcut

restore `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcut` >> NOT WORKING

delete `~/Library/Preferences/om.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist` >> NOT WORKING

Can anyone help me to find out what is going on?

OSX version is 10.11 and Xcode 7.3

Comment: You could just [reset XCode shortcut keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611531/reset-xcode-shortcut-keys)

Comment: thx, I just try to reset. but it still not working...